# "Knob" vs. "knoll" in AmE

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage

The Harrap's New Shorter French and English Dictionary Ed. 1985, defines one of the senses of "knob" as an AmE equivalent for "knoll", i.e. a small, rounded hill or eminence; hillock.

Sadly enough, it doesn't say if this so-called Americanism was to some extent more commonly used back in the 80s than its shared synonym, nor if it ever caught on in AmE in that sense.

And so, I wish you could tell if "knob" for "knoll" has any currency at all in AmE today. Or does it sound unequivocally archaic to your ears?

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Knob?s=t
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/knoll?s=t

E.g.

> The knoll upon which Jacksland stood overlooked the river, just a grassy knob that felt peaceful and untouched... [source](https://www.encorepub.com/welcome/a-soft-place-to-sleep/)

Comment: In Britain I have never heard 'knob' used for that purpose, and 'knoll' is only seldom used. 'Hillock' or 'high ground' would be more likely.

Comment: The most famous _knoll_ that immediately came to mind was the _grassy knoll_ that figures in the JFK assassination. American press surely didn't choose to call it _knob_ then - and I have actually never heard _knob_ in that sense. And _knoll_ I do know mostly because of JFK... Then again, I am not American.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it would be difficult to find an American that would understand you were talking about a hill if called a 'knob'.

People understand what a grassy 'knoll' is - the place where JFK was shot from, but they wouldn't use it to describe a hill.

Far more likely that it would be referred to as a hill, slope or incline depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

Knob - is used all the time for a small round projectile that turns.  Like door knob or knob for car radio.

Knoll - is lightly used for a small hill or embankment.  It definitely gets its play from the JFK assassination remakes but I wouldn't say that it is only used there.  It is not a common term but it is understood.